# 16.04/Dell XPS 15 9560 freezes/keyboard not working on login

Tags: 16.04

tldr: Ubuntu login screen: keyboard doesn't work/ubuntu freezes. Used install usb to run boot-repair. This generated this paste: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vnNdS8pDdR/

16.04/Dell XPS 15 9560 freezes/keyboard not working on login. I recently reinstalled linux, and it was working perfectly, until at one point i shut down the device, and got a cpu lockup[23s] message. It wouldn't power down. I used the alt + print screen + R > S > E > I > U > B combination to shut down.

From the reboot and forward, the mouse began to stop working on boot, and intermittently for 2-10s at a time. I did some research updated nvidia drivers, and attempted to turn off the nouveau drivers. The device will not allow me to log in now.

I used a usb drive to install boot-repair, and ran it. It still doesn't work. This has happened 4 times during my use of this laptop over the last year. It always happens after an update from the application manager. How do I fix/avoid this, so that I can actually use linux reliably? I use this for software development, so I only install: Visual Studio Code, Chrome, MongoDB, npm, yarn, node, and the typescript compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I could fix it with a modification of `/etc/default/grub` file. I added a parameter to line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. Now it looks like

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_rev_override=1"
```

Don't forget `update-grub` once you changed this file